# Author Name from bib Does Not Appear in The Reference

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, bibliographystyle

I cited several journals and used bib to display the reference in the overleaf.

centralbib.bib

```
@ARTICLE{jlee14, 
author={Lee, Jun-Ho and Kim, Hyun-Jung and Lee, Tae-Eog}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Automation Science and Engineering}, 
title={Scheduling Cluster Tools for Concurrent Processing of Two Wafer Types}, 
year={2014}, 
month={April}, 
volume={11}, 
number={2}, 
pages={525-536}, 
}

@article{lee2015scheduling,
  title={Scheduling cluster tools for concurrent processing of two wafer types with PM sharing},
  author={Lee, Jun-Ho and Kim, Hyun-Jung and Lee, Tae-Eog},
  journal={International Journal of Production Research},
  volume={53},
  number={19},
  pages={6007--6022},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

abcded \cite{jlee14, lee2015scheduling}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{centralbib.bib}
\end{document}
```

However, when I compile in the overleaf, the author name does not appear on the pdf file as in the following screenshot.

[image]

What needs to be corrected?

Comment: If two or more entries have the same author (or same list of authors), the `IEEEtran` bibliography style is programmed to replace the `author` block with `------` from the second instance onward. This replacement tends to save quite a bit of space. This is a deliberate stylistic choice. If you don't agree with this choice, you probably sholdn't be using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.

Comment: Hi @Mico, oh, understood. So, the ------ in this case is similar to idem. Initially, I thought there is some error since the author name does not appear. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: By the way, if you are submitting to IEEE, you are most likely to use the journal name in the abbreviation. You can take advantage of the `IEEEabrv.bib`, which defines for example `IEEE_J_IT` as `{IEEE} Trans. Inf. Theory`.